# Ubuntu Server 12.10 Sleep & Wake up?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.10

I just got my Ubuntu Server 12.10 up and running, but when I am away or the server is idle for a certain amount of time, I want my server to **sleep** but also turn back on when I want it to via ssh.

Is it possible to make it sleep/wake up via SSH?

Comment: Isn't the point of servers to stay online all the time? If you really want to, you can implement wake on LAN: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/02/ubuntu-server-suspendhibernateresume.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutley, you just need to setup Wake On Lan:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan